# Create unique random numbers using srand and rand function(php)?

Tags: php

This code creates a new random number each second.

```
   srand(floor(time() / (1)));
   echo rand(0,5);
```

How can it echo random numbers (0-5) uniquely, and then cycle?

For example, I'd love to get a sequence like this:

```
1,5,4,3,2,1,4,5,3,2,5,4,1,2,3...
```

Rather than this:

```
2,2,1,4,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,1,2,3,4...
```

(Just to clarify, the second gap is important, and you're to assume there's been a one second delay between each page load. Each page load results in a random number)

Answer (score 0):

do you want to get rid of sequences like "2,2" and "5,5,5,5"? it's possible only if you store previous number somewhere, e.g. in $_SESSION superglobal var:

```
session_start();
$ran_num = rand(0, 5);
while ($ran_num == $_SESSION['ran_num']) {
    $ran_num = rand(0, 5);
}
$_SESSION['ran_num'] = $ran_num;
echo $ran_num;
```

Comment: Yes, I want to get rid of the same number coming up for each 5 numbers generated, if you follow me. I'll admit I'm slightly confused as to how how seeding works. What my code does is store a random number for a second, before it changes it. By changing the srand parameters, you can have php store this number for a week, month, or even a decade. I had no idea php and apache could do this. 
Can you do the same with a session superglobal array? Storing the past numbers indefinitely, so all users would see the same unique random numbers?

Comment: I think you're seriously confused about what `srand()` does. It doesn't cause anything to be permanently stored anywhere.

Comment: If you want your numbers to be persisted indefinitely, you would need to look at storing them in files or in a database

Comment: seeding the random generator won't help you, it can return any number after it (it's random generator!)

5 after 5 is not less random as any other number (sorry for my english)

the only way is to store previous number somewhere:

Comment: 1. $_SESSION (for only 1 session), 2. $_COOKIE (till 3:14:07 GMT on January 19, 2038, but user can delete it unexpectedly) and as _wwarren_ sad in 3. mysql DB forever but user must be authenticated